# Absolute Value of the Differences In Two (2) Ranges - PART II

Tags: excel, vba, range

Hopefully this is easier to read than yesterday. Trying to find a way to vary the number of periods "N" that measure "VOLATILITY"  The code for the complete function as suggested yesterday is below and fixes "N" at 10. Function works just fine for KAMA with the default value for "N" (N0Addr and N1Addr are not needed in this default version of the KAMA function but are steps to get to a variable "N")

This formula works in Excel:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ABS(I26:I36-I25:I35)))
```

I can also obtain the correct sum of differences in the two ranges but not the absolute value. This VBA Code does that with the named ranges "N0Addr" and "N1Addr":

```
Rng0 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N0Addr)) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N1Addr))
```

---

```
Function nTEST(Price, nPer, mPer, N)        
    'Variables
    Fast = 2 / (nPer + 1)
    Slow = 2 / (mPer + 1)


    'One(1) Prior Period Calculation
    nTEST1 = Application.Caller.Offset(-1)

    N0Addr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(Price.Offset(-N, 0).Address & ":" & Price.Address)
    N1Addr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Concat(Price.Offset(-(N + 1), 0).Address & ":" & (Price.Offset(-1, 0).Address))

    'Change Formula (Y - Yn)
    E = Abs(Price - Price.Offset(-N, 0))

    'Volatility Formula { =SUM(ABS(Y:Yn)-(Y1:Yn1))) }
    'VOLATILITY (N = 10)
    '1-10
    R = Abs(Price - Price.Offset(-1, 0)) + Abs(Price.Offset(-1, 0) - Price.Offset(-2, 0)) _
         + Abs(Price.Offset(-2, 0) - Price.Offset(-3, 0)) _
        + Abs(Price.Offset(-3, 0) - Price.Offset(-4, 0)) + Abs(Price.Offset(-4, 0) - Price.Offset(-5, 0)) _
        + Abs(Price.Offset(-5, 0) - Price.Offset(-6, 0)) + Abs(Price.Offset(-6, 0) - Price.Offset(-7, 0)) _
        + Abs(Price.Offset(-7, 0) - Price.Offset(-8, 0)) + Abs(Price.Offset(-8, 0) - Price.Offset(-9, 0)) _
        + Abs(Price.Offset(-9, 0) - Price.Offset(-10, 0))

    'EFFICIENCY RATIO
    ER = E / R

    Smooth = (ER * (Fast - Slow) + Slow) ^ 2

    'Formula Calculation
    nKAMA = Smooth * Price + (1 - Smooth) * nKAMA1

End Function
```

Looking for an VBA formula or method to input a working formula for "volatility" that can vary over N periods. I can get the sum of differences but not the sum of absolute differences.

```
Rng0 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N0Addr)) - WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(N1Addr))
```

I can also enter one formula in Excel that accomplishes provides the sum of absolute differences.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ABS(I26:I36-I25:I35)))
```

Comment: Actually it's completly unclear to me. Could you please [edit] your question and include some example data and what exactly the outcome should be? that would make it easier to understand (see [mcve]). Screenshots might help here too.

Comment: Looking for a means to calculate "R" using ranges or arrays without having to enter (as above) one at a time the sum of a series of separate absolute differences. R is the denominator in a ratio for calculating a smoothing factor in an adaptive moving average.  R is the sum of the absolute value of single period differences in price over N periods. SUM (ABS(Y-Y1 + … Yn-1 - Yn))

Comment: Use a for Loop: `For i = 1 to 10` then `R = R + ABS(Price.Offset(-i+1,0)-Price.Offset(-i,0))`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer and the code.

Comment: Again, many thanks for the assistance. Works quite nicely.